# Kimball Data: Modeling Data as Both Fact and Dimension with View

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-warehouse, sql-server-2017

In Data warehousing, Kimball discusses modeling an insurance policy premium as Both Dimension and Fact.
I have the following table,

```
create table dbo.DimAutoInsurance
(
    DimAutoInsuranceId int primary key identity(1,1),
    CustomerName varchar(100),
    CustomerAddress varchar(255),
    PolicyCoverageAmount numeric (15,2), 
    PolicyBeginDate datetime,
    PolicyExpirationDate datetime
)
```

For the Fact table, should I reconduct ETL another table for fact? Copying the data again, would seem redundant. 
Or should I create a view? What is best database design strategy?

```
create view dbo.FactAutoInsurance
as 
select
    DimAutoInsuranceId,
    PolicyCoverageAmount numeric (10,2), 
from dbo.DimAutoInsurance
```

https://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/12/design-tip-97-modeling-data-as-both-a-fact-and-dimension-attribute/

**Kimball:**

> "A more ambiguous example is the limit on a coverage within an
>   automobile insurance policy. The limit is a numerical data item, say
>   $300,000 for collision liability. Furthermore, many queries would
>   group or constrain on this limit data item. This sounds like a slam
>   dunk for the limit being an attribute of the coverage dimension.
>
> One could pose some important queries summing or averaging all the
>   limits on many policies and coverages. This sounds like a slam dunk
>   for the limit being a numeric fact in a fact table. Rather than
>   agonizing over the dimension versus fact choice, simply model it BOTH
>   ways! Include the limit in the coverage dimension so that it
>   participates in the usual way as a target for constraints and the
>   content for row headers, but also put the limit in the fact table so
>   it can participate in the usual way within complex computations."

Comment: Not and answer, but whether you use a view or a table is an implementation detail, not part of your logical data model.  Use a view if it performs well enough; load a table from the view if it doesn't.

Comment: why was this question voted down? trying to learn

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not clear what question you're asking.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

[Kimball's page](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/12/design-tip-97-modeling-data-as-both-a-fact-and-dimension-attribute/) that you are quoting says:

> **numerical** measurements that we put into **fact** tables, and **textual**
>   descriptors that we put into **dimension** tables as “attributes”

According to Wikipedia's page `Star_schema`:

> Fact tables record measurements or metrics for a specific event. Fact
>   tables generally consist of numeric values, and foreign keys to
>   dimensional data where descriptive information is kept. [...]
>   Fact tables are defined as one of
>   three types:
>
> - Transaction fact tables record facts about a specific event (e.g.,
>     sales events)
> - Snapshot fact tables record facts at a given point in
>     time (e.g., account details at month end)
> - Accumulating snapshot tables
>     record aggregate facts at a given point in time (e.g., total
>     month-to-date sales for a product)

and

> Dimension tables usually have a relatively small
>   number of records compared to fact tables, but each record may have a
>   very large number of attributes to describe the fact data.

So, there is a one-to-many relationship between the **dimension** table records and the **fact** table records.

In your case, I would expect **fact** table to have a date as one of the fields, and it represents time snapshot of the values for that particular date.

If you include, for example, `PolicyCoverageAmount` in both tables, it will represent the current value in the `DimAutoInsurance` table, and value at a specific time in the `FactAutoInsurance` table.

Yes, the same number will be in two places. But the idea is to optimize for querying instead of normalizing, so some redundancy is expected.